# Creating parameters to stop sql injection

Tags: php, sql, pdo, parameters, code-injection

Right now i have a site that i need to secure from basic SQL injection attacks. The site is very basic, just a form for login and a product search page. Right now i have a file where i am keeping all of my functions used on the website. Here is a couple examples of what they look like:

```
function createUser($userName,$userPass){
$query = <<<STR
INSERT INTO Users (userName,userPass,userTypeID)
VALUES ('$userName','$userPass',2)
STR;
return executeQuery($query);
}
```

Or

```
function getProductByName($productName){
$query = <<<STR
SELECT productID,productName, productPic,productDesc 
FROM Products
WHERE productName LIKE '%$productName%'
STR;


return executeQuery($query);
}
```

I want to change these so that they make use of prepared statements but am having trouble understanding how i can convert them. I found examples that make use of bindParam such as this one:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName,Address,City) 
VALUES (:nam, :add, :cit)");
$stmt->bindParam(':nam', $txtNam);
$stmt->bindParam(':add', $txtAdd)
$stmt->bindParam(':cit', $txtCit);
$stmt->execute();
```

Can i incorporate bindparam into my functions somehow? Any leads would be great.

Answer (score 1):

To convert them, just do the `prepare()` and `bindParam()` parts in your shown functions and the `execute()` in the `executeQuery()` function like this

```
function createUser($userName,$userPass,$dbh) {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Users (userName, userPass, userTypeID) VALUES (:name, :pass, :id)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $userName);
    //etc
    return executeQuery($stmt);
}

function executeQuery($stmt) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

If you don't want to inject the `$dbh`, you can use `global $dbh;` or similar methods in the function (and don't have to change your existing code base).

But of course this will be very repetitive, as you need to write multiple `bindParam()` statements. The simpler way, assuming you are using PDO, would be to pass an array to `execute()` ([as shown in the manual](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.execute.php))

```
function createUser($userName,$userPass,$dbh) {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Users (userName, userPass, userTypeID) VALUES (:name, :pass, :id)");
    $params = array(
        ':name' => $userName,
        //etc
    );
    return executeQuery($stmt, $params);
}

function executeQuery($stmt, $params) {
    $stmt->execute($params);
}
```

---

To elaborate a bit: The real power of `bindParam()` comes when you a) want to use the `$data_type` or `$length` parameters ([What are those?](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.bindparam.php)) or b) when you are using multiple `execute()` statements, eg a bulk insert

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (:name)");
$stmt->bindParam(":name", $name);
for (...) {
    $name = ...
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. This may be a stupid question but one thing i am confused about is this line here:
    `$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (:name)");` 
what is $dbh doing? Should this be declared somewhere else? Is this the database connection? I see some people online declaring is as 
    `<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
?>`
is this right?

Comment: @SheepCity It is the "db handler", so it holds information about the connection, correct. And the code you posted looks right, for more information please read the [official manual](http://php.net/pdo). Why is this necessary? You may have multiple databases and so you can differentiate between them. Previously PHP assumed, now you need to tell it explicitly